# Change the pagination number link Url in WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using WebGrid.

I am unable to change the url of the page number. like when I click on page number "1" it goes to the URL `/Products/BasicWebGrid`.

However i want to change the Url to `/Product/TestWebGrid`.

Any suggestion how can I achieve it?

Comment: You want to redirect to another page in pagination link?

Comment: yes in another page or may be in another action Method

Comment: Then how come it is pagination? just remove the pagination and try action link